# Understanding macro measuring array count from glut tutorial

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, macros

I am learning/reading a bit of openGL. I am currently following the tutorials from http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/ . The program has a macro which is used for array length. I know array length is counted as `(sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] )`.

But the code has some additional stuff so the final macro is :

```
#define ARRAY_COUNT( array ) (sizeof( array ) / (sizeof( array[0] ) * (sizeof( array ) != sizeof(void*) || sizeof( array[0] ) <= sizeof(void*))))
```

I am unable to understand why is it being multiplied by a `bool`.

Comment: It's "protecting" itself against being used on pointers.

Comment: Indeed. But it's non-robust, and it's arguable that returning 0 is not helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it seems pretty pointless. If you have a `char *`, `sizeof(arr[0]) <= sizeof(void *)` must be true, so it will still count. Considering this is C++, you can write a `constexpr` function to achieve the same thing, or a regular one to have the result at runtime. Of course you could also just use `std::array` or `boost::array`.

Answer (score 1):

The addition is to check some bad usages of pointer instead of array as:

```
long long buf[42];
long long *p = buf; 

ARRAY_COUNT(p); // this produces a compilation error : division by zero.
```

but it fails to detect some bad usages as:

```
char buf[42];
char *p = buf; 

ARRAY_COUNT(p); // this gives unexpected result.
```

The check cannot detect bad usage for types which have a size less or equal than a pointer.

The C++ way to do that is:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t ArraySize(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```